# Bowden setup keeps jamming between PTFE tube and heatsink

Tags: bowden, e3d-v6

I keep getting a jam where the PTFE tube meets the top of the v6 hot end. I have the PTFE tube all the away in but for some reason it gets a bulge at that spot and will stop printing. It happens with or without retraction. Any ideas?

Comment: I am thinking you mean the middle of the cold end instead of the hot end; above the top of the heat break. Could you add a sketch? Sometimes chamfering the tube helps!

Comment: Do you have cooling fan for the e3d heatsink ?

Comment: Can you show a picture of your setup?

Answer (score 1):

Filament sometimes get stuck on the rim of the PTFE tubes inside the heat sink. Josef Prusa from Prusa Research has published a document on how you should chamfer the PTFE tubes for his printers:

[image: Josef Prusa PTFE tube chamfering]

Maybe chamfering your tubes works for you too.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. Sorry I took so long to respond. I didn't get a notification of your responses. I'd like to to try this chamfer of the ptfe tube but this seems like a difficult thing to pull off accurately with a tiny round tube. Do you think a pencil sharpener would work?

Comment: @Hellrazor You can find printed objects on Thingiverse, if you are still able to print small parts; e.g. [this](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:3121653).